# How to give the user some assigned time to answer?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, timer

Something like a stopwatch, give the person who is using my program about 30 second to answer, if no answer is got the program to exit ? 
Basically the response shouldn't take more than the time given, otherwise the program will exit.

Comment: this sounds like a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is exiting from a background thread acceptable? Otherwise waiting for input at the console with a timer will require OS specific implementations.

Comment: Nah , but I think this could be done by using the `ctype`- `time.h` header , but i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use *exit* and kill the process you could do it this way:

```
std::string getInputWithin(int timeoutInSeconds, bool *noInput = nullptr)
{
    std::string answer;

    bool exceeded = false;
    bool gotInput = false;

    auto r1 = std::async([&answer, &gotInput]()
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, answer);
        gotInput = true;
    });

    auto r2 = std::async([&timeoutInSeconds, &exceeded]()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        exceeded = true;
    });

    while(!gotInput && !exceeded)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }

    if(gotInput)
    {
        if(noInput != nullptr) *noInput = false;
        return answer;
    }

    if(noInput != nullptr) *noInput = true;
    return "";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "please answer within 10 seconds...\n";

    bool noInput;
    std::string answer = getInputWithin(10, &noInput);

    return 0;
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you can now handle the missing input by using a default value or simply give the user a second chance, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by Axalo interesting, however fatally flawed by unfortunate minutia of `std::async` and `std::future`.  So I'm presenting an alternative that eschews `std::async` but otherwise follows Axalo's basic design.

When I run Axalo's answer on my platform (which is conforming in the pertinent details), if the client never answers, `getInputWithin` never returns or exits.  The program just hangs.  And if the client answers well within the timeout, `getInputWithin` returns with the correct answer, but doesn't do so until the timeout period has expired.

The reason for this problem is subtle.  It is well described in [Herb Sutter's excellent paper N3630](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3630.pdf).  A `~std::future()` can block if it was returned by `std::async()` and will block until the associated task is done.  This feature was intentionally put into `async/future`, and in the eyes of some, makes `future` completely useless.

Axalo's `r1` and `r2` are such `std::future`s whose destructor is supposed to block until the associated task is done.  And this is why this solution hangs if the client never answers.

Below is an alternative answer which is built from `thread`, `mutex`, and `condition_variable`.  It is otherwise very similar to Axalo's answer, but does not suffer from (what some consider) the design flaws of `std::async`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>

std::string
getInputWithin(std::chrono::seconds timeout)
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<std::tuple<std::mutex, std::condition_variable,
                                          std::string, bool>>();
    std::thread([sp]() mutable
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, std::get<2>(*sp));
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(std::get<0>(*sp));
        std::get<3>(*sp) = true;
        std::get<1>(*sp).notify_one();
        sp.reset();
    }).detach();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(std::get<0>(*sp));
    if (!std::get<1>(*sp).wait_for(lk, timeout, [&]() {return std::get<3>(*sp);}))
        throw std::runtime_error("time out");
    return std::get<2>(*sp);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "please answer within 10 seconds...\n";
    std::string answer = getInputWithin(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << answer << '\n';
}
```

Notes:

- The timing stays within the `chrono` type system *always*.  Prefer the type `std::chrono::seconds` to a scalar with a suggestive name (`int timeoutInSeconds` vs `std::chrono::seconds timeout`).
- We need to launch a `std::thread` to handle the read from `std::cin`, as Axalo demonstrated.  However we are going to need a `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` for communication instead of using the convenience of `std::future`.  Both the main thread and this auxiliary thread need to share ownership of these communication objects, and we don't know which will die first.  If the client never responds, the  auxiliary thread may live forever, creating an effective memory leak, which is another problem not solved herein.  But at any rate, the easiest way to share ownership is to store the communication objects with a **copied** `std::shared_ptr`.  Last one out turns out the lights.
- Launch a `std::thread` that waits for `std::cin` and signals the main thread if it gets it.  The signaling must be done with the `mutex` locked.  Note that this `thread` can be (indeed must be) detached.  The `thread` can not touch any memory that it does not own (because of the `shared_ptr` owning all referenced memory).  If `main` exits while the auxiliary thread is running, the OS will bring the thread down gracefully with no UB.
- The main thread then locks the `mutex` and does a `wait_for` on the `condition_variable` using the specified timeout, and a predicate that is checking for the `bool` in the `tuple` to turn to `true`.  This `wait_for` will either return early with that `bool` set to `true`, or it will return with it set to `false` after `timeout` seconds.  If they race (timeout and client answer at the same time) it is ok, either there will be a `string` there or not, and the `bool` in the `tuple` answers that question.  While
  the main thread is executing the `wait_for`, the `mutex` is unlocked so the auxiliary thread can use it.
- If the main thread returns and the `bool` in the `tuple` has not been set to `true`, then an exception is thrown.  If this exception is not caught, `std::terminate()` will be called.  Otherwise, the `string` in the `tuple` will have the client's response.
- This approach is susceptible to a client creating many responses to which it never answers, and thus effectively growing memory leaks held by `shared_ptr`s which never get destructed.  Solving that problem is not something I know how to do in portable C++.

In C++14, a slight modification can be done with `getInputWithin` which reduces the error of choosing the wrong member of the `tuple`.  Since our `tuple` is composed of all different types, we can index it by type instead of by position:

```
std::string
getInputWithin(std::chrono::seconds timeout)
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<std::tuple<std::mutex, std::condition_variable,
                                          std::string, bool>>();
    std::thread([sp]() mutable
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, std::get<std::string>(*sp));  // here
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(std::get<std::mutex>(*sp));  // here
        std::get<bool>(*sp) = true;  // here
        std::get<std::condition_variable>(*sp).notify_one();  // here
        sp.reset();
    }).detach();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(std::get<std::mutex>(*sp));  // here
    if (!std::get<std::condition_variable>(*sp).wait_for(lk, timeout,
                                           [&]() {return std::get<bool>(*sp);}))  // here
        throw std::runtime_error("time out");
    return std::get<std::string>(*sp);  // here
}
```

That is, the lines marked `// here` have been changed with `std::get<type>(*sp)` as opposed to `std::get<index>(*sp)`.

**Update**

In a fit of paranoia inspired by the good comment from [TemplateRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819272/templaterex) below, I've added a call to `sp.reset()` as the last thing the aux thread does.  This forces the main thread to be the one to destruct the `tuple`, eliminating the possibility that the aux thread could stall before destructing its local copy of `sp`, and let main blow through the atexit chain, and then have the aux thread wake up and run the `tuple` destructor.

There may be other reasons that exist to make the call to `sp.reset()` unnecessary.  But by adding this preventative medicine, we don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Re the OS killing the detached thread, does the Standard guarantee it (and where?) or is that QoI from OS vendors?

Comment: 3.3.3 [basic.start.term] discusses this issue and clearly states that if code accesses standard library objects (such as std::cin) after the "atexit chain" which I mean to include static destructors, then you're in UB land.  However if the program ends with an uncaught exception, that will call `terminate()`, which by default calls `abort()`, which ends the program without executing the "atexit chain".  That pretty much just yanks the power cord out from under your application (including all threads).

Comment: Otoh, if main exits normally, then by the logic set up by `getInputWithin`, the aux thread will not be touching anything after releasing the lock on the mutex except for the shared_ptr reference counts which may invoke the destructor on that tuple.  The aux thread and main race to see who destructs the tuple.  One will win and one will skip that step.  If main races ahead and blasts through the atexit chain before the aux thread completes destructing the tuple and cleaning itself up, there may be some theoretical UB, but that sounds pretty far fetched to me.

Comment: I suppose adding `sp. reset()` as the last thing the aux thread does would eliminate that possibility.  I'll go ahead and add that to the code.